# Rust mod facing the issue error: file not found for module bytes

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project which contains three files main.rs,bytes.rs and provider.rs. I have created mod.rs file and I have included both crate bytes.rs and provider.rs as shown below. whenever I am trying to include `mod bytes` inside the provider.rs, I get the error, please help me to sort out this.

> error: file not found for module `bytes`

```
 ---projectA
      + src
       --   main.rs
       --   mod.rs
       --   bytes.rs
       --   provider.rs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created mod.rs file

That was completely unnecessary:

1. mod.rs is only for *subfolders* of the root folder. For the root, there is already a crate root (main.rs or lib.rs) so there is no situation in which this file is useful
2. and in edition 2018 mod.rs [is not necessary for sub-mods to work](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#no-more-modrs) (though it is still allowed I think)

You should just have `mod bytes; mod provider` in the crate root (`main.rs`). Then, `provider.rs` can either:

- use the item from bytes directly e.g. `super::bytes::...` or `crate::bytes::...` will resolve to the relevant symbol from the `bytes` sibling module
- `use` a similar path in order to use "short forms" for symbols e.g. `use super::bytes::Foo` will let the module refer to `Foo` without needing the fully qualified path

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687811/8182118 for more, as well as a description of edition 2015.