# How to use structures from sibling/adjacent rust file?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to edit a Rust project with the following structure:

```
src/iface/ip.rs

src/iface/tun.rs
```

I want to call things from `ip.rs` inside `tun.rs`. So on `tun.rs` I added:

```
use iface::ip;
```

but it says

```
unresolved import `iface::ip`

no `ip` in `iface`rustc(E0432)
```

This seems to be the way to do it as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687811/6655884 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26390046/6655884

I also tried `mod ip` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Does your parent `lib.rs` or `mod.rs` actually `use` them?

Comment: @tadman on `lib.rs` there's the line `pub mod iface;` so it's 'importing' everything inside iface isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In `iface/mod.rs`

`pub mod ip;`

#### In `iface/tun.rs`

`use crate::iface::ip;`