# Why can't I use use crate::utils?

Tags: rust

The question is simple: Why can't I use `use crate::utils`?

If I understood correctly, the `crate` refers to the root of my crate. I've just generated a new library project that by default has a `lib.rs` and `utils.rs` file and although I understand why `mod utils` work, I don't understand why `use crate::utils` wouldn't.

Comment: You need `mod utils;` for `utils.rs` to be even considered a part of the project by the compiler. If you don't declare that module, the file will be ignored, and there simply isn't any `crate::utils` to be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a module across several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596920/split-a-module-across-several-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use structures from sibling/adjacent rust file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61947573/how-to-use-structures-from-sibling-adjacent-rust-file)