# How to include a file in two files (including main) in rust and directly use its namespace name in both files?

Tags: rust

I have this structure:

```
src
|   main.rs
|   fcfs.rs
|   proc.rs
```

I want to include `proc.rs` in both `main.rs` and `fcfs.rs`. Initially, I used `mod proc` in both files. This only worked in `main.rs`, and it did *not* work in `fcfs.rs`

Consulting SO, I found an answer in which the *path* attribute was described.

so I have the three files as follows:

```
// proc.rs
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Proc {
    name: String,
    cpu_burst: u32, 
    priority: u32,
    time_rem: u32,
}

impl Proc {
    pub fn new(name: String,
        cpu_burst: u32,
        priority: u32,
        time_rem: u32) -> Proc {
        Proc {
            name, 
            cpu_burst,
            priority,
            time_rem,
        }
    }
}
```

```
// fcfs.rs
#![allow(dead_code)]

#[path = "./proc.rs"] mod proc;
use proc::*;

pub struct FCFSScheduler {
    procs: Vec<Proc>,
}

impl FCFSScheduler {
    pub fn new() -> FCFSScheduler {
        FCFSScheduler {
            procs: Vec::<Proc>::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, t: proc::Proc) {
        self.procs.push(t);
    }
}
```

```
// main.rs
#![allow(dead_code)]

mod proc;
mod fcfs;

use proc::*;
use fcfs::*;

fn main() {
    let t = Proc::new(String::from("T1"), 1, 1, 1);
    let mut s = FCFSScheduler::new(); 
    s.add(t);
}
```

The problem with me is with the `s.add(t)` line in `main.rs`.

I get the following problem.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:12:11
   |
12 |     s.add(t);
   |           ^ expected struct `fcfs::proc::Proc`, found struct `proc::Proc`
```

This is solved by changing `t` to a `fcfs::proc::Proc`, but I want to know about the better way to manage imports because this does not sound scalable at all. How can I simply include `proc.rs` and just use `proc::Proc` everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `#[path = ..]` like this will make Rust think that `proc.rs` is two separate modules instead of one, which is why you get the confusing *"expected Proc, found Proc"* error message.

Keep the module defined in `main.rs`:

```
mod proc;
```

And you can access the module via its path in `fcfs.rs` like so:

```
use crate::proc::*;
```

See also:

- [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module)