# How to use a trait in multiple modules

Tags: rust, module

While trying to DRY and reorganize some code in a project, I'm running into issues with scoping and modules.

`src/main.rs`:

```
mod account;
use account::Account;

mod vacancy;
use vacancy::Vacancy;

fn main() {
   let key = String::from("s3cr3t");
   let uri = String::from("https://localhost:7700");

   let account = Account { name: String::from("jdoe") };
   account.into_meili(&uri, &key);

   let vacancy = Vacancy { title: String::from("CEO") };
   vacancy.into_meili(&uri, &key);
}
```

`src/account.rs`:

```
pub struct Account {
    name: String
}
impl IntoMeili for Account {
    fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String) {
        println!("storing document in {} using {}", uri, key);
    }
}
```

`src/vacancy.rs`:

```
pub struct Vacancy {
    title: String
}
impl IntoMeili for Vacancy {
    fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String) {
        println!("storing document in {} using {}", uri, key);
    }
}
```

`src/into_meili.rs`:

```
pub trait IntoMeili {
    fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String);
}
```

I'm at a loss how to tie these together. I may have gotten some concept entirely wrong, though, so maybe the structure is mistaken in the first place.

When I bring `into_meili` into scope in the two modules, I need to tell about the [path attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute), which hints that my structure is un-rust-full to begin with:

`src/vacancy.rs`:

```
#[path="into_meili.rs"]
mod into_meili;
use into_meili::IntoMeili;
// ... same as above.
```

Same in `src/account.rs`. This gets rid of the obvious *not found in this scope* errors for IntoMeili.

This returns the errors to `src/main.rs`, in the form of *method not found in `Vacancy`* for `account.into_meili()`. The suggestion is to bring the `IntoMeili` into scope. With a weird suggestion: `use crate::account::into_meili::IntoMeili;`. Hinting that, again, my structure is wrong, as I want to bring `crate::into_meili::IntoMeili` in scope instead?

Both suggestions don't work. If I bring `use crate::account::into_meili::IntoMeili;` and `use crate::vacancy::into_meili::IntoMeili;` it errors with `private module` for `into_meili`.

When I use `mod into_meili; use into_meili::IntoMeili;` I still get *method not found in `Vacancy`*, because, apparently, this is the wrong trait according to this structure.

I probably don't understand a concept in Rust correct; there's a lot to learn in Rust. Obviously the examples are simplified greatly, and because I'm *fighting the compiler*, above code won't compile. I've added a compiling version in the footnotes, which simply keeps modules out of it entirely.

So, how would I structure my project?

- I can duplicate the trait and simply have both *vacancy* and *account* define the trait.
- Am I misunderstanding or misusing, the idea of a trait entirely?
- Am I structuring the code and modules wrong?
- Is it "rust-ish" at all to define methods like `fn into_meili` on objects in the first place, rather than having e.g. a `meili::vacancy_into_meili()` etc?
- Anything else I'm getting completely ur subtly wrong?
  (or all of above?)

---

Compiling example [on rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4bf06ca24a23f958ba1fe635631ef0d4):

```
pub trait IntoMeili {
    fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String);
}

pub struct Account {
    name: String
}
impl IntoMeili for Account {
    fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String) {
        println!("storing document in {} using {}", uri, key);
    }
}

pub struct Vacancy {
    title: String
}
impl IntoMeili for Vacancy {
    fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String) {
        println!("storing document in {} using {}", uri, key);
    }
}

fn main() {
   let key = String::from("s3cr3t");
   let uri = String::from("https://localhost:7700");

   let account = Account { name: String::from("jdoe") };
   account.into_meili(&uri, &key);

   let vacancy = Vacancy { title: String::from("CEO") };
   vacancy.into_meili(&uri, &key);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I structuring the code and modules wrong?

Its mostly that you've not yet understood how files and modules link together. You should *never* have to use the `#[path = ...]` attribute. Your `main.rs` should *declare* that the other files exist via `mod`:

```
mod account; // you already
mod vacancy; // have these

mod into_meili; // add this
```

Then to access the `into_meili` module to implement the trait for `Account` and `Vacancy`, you can import it via:

```
use crate::into_meili::IntoMeili;
// or
use super::into_meili::IntoMeili;
```

See: [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module)

So your *working* example is more akin to this:

```
// into_meili.rs
mod into_meili {
    pub trait IntoMeili {
        fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String);
    }
}

// account.rs
mod account {
    use super::into_meili::IntoMeili;

    pub struct Account {
        name: String
    }
    impl IntoMeili for Account {
        fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String) {
            println!("storing document in {} using {}", uri, key);
        }
    }
}

// vacancy.rs
mod vacancy {
    use super::into_meili::IntoMeili;

    pub struct Vacancy {
        title: String
    }
    impl IntoMeili for Vacancy {
        fn into_meili(&self, uri: &String, key: &String) {
            println!("storing document in {} using {}", uri, key);
        }
    }
}

// main.rs
use account::Account;
use vacancy::Vacancy;
use into_meili::IntoMeili;

fn main() {
   let key = String::from("s3cr3t");
   let uri = String::from("https://localhost:7700");

   let account = Account { name: String::from("jdoe") };
   account.into_meili(&uri, &key);

   let vacancy = Vacancy { title: String::from("CEO") };
   vacancy.into_meili(&uri, &key);
}
```

For more explanation I think the blogs [Clear explanation of Rust’s module system](http://www.sheshbabu.com/posts/rust-module-system/) and [Rust modules vs files](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/rust-modules-vs-files) do a good job of explaining things.

---

Other than that, your code looks fine to me.

> Is it "rust-ish" at all to define methods like `fn into_meili` on objects in the first place, rather than having e.g. a `meili::vacancy_into_meili()` etc?

Both have their uses, but you'd use traits if both `Account` and `Vacancy` are intended to be treated similarly/generically.

Comment: the super* and the fact that "child" modules autoatatically get the modules from their parents, where my missing pieces of knowledge.