# How to correctly include files in rust?

Tags: rust, module, include

I've just started learning rust and having trouble including files.

So my problem is that when I want to use a `struct` from `a.rs` in `b.rs` the only way I got it to work is by the absolute path. So `use crate::stuff::a::StructA;`. From what I've read,  I should be able use `mod` here because it's in the same module.

To get to my question, for someone who has a background in c/c++ and python how I should  include things correctly? (Because this absolute path really feels inconvenient.)

---

Directory structure:

```
src
├── stuff
│   ├── a.rs
│   ├── b.rs
│   └── c.rs
├── stuff.rs
└── main.rs
```

`b.rs`:

```rust
use crate::stuff::a::StructA;

/* doesn't work
mod stuff;
use stuff::a::StructA;
*/
/* doesn't work
mod a;
use a::StructA;
*/

// Works but why should I define the path. It's in the same dir/mod.
#[path = "a.rs"]
mod a;
use a::StructA;
```

`stuff.rs`:

```rust
pub mod a;
pub mod b;
pub mod c;
```

`main.rs`:

```rust
use crate::stuff::a::StructA;
use crate::stuff::b::StructB;
use crate::stuff::c::StructC;

fn main() {
    let a = StructA::new();
    let b = StructB::new(a);
    let c = StructC::new(a, b);
}
```

`b.rs` and `c.rs` uses parts of `a.rs`. `main.rs` uses `a.rs`, `b.rs` and `c.rs`.

Edit:
I've also read that usage of `mod.rs` is not recommended.

Comment: Have you seen [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module) You would import `StructA` into `b.rs` via `use super::a::StructA`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mod` keyword is only used for defining modules, since you did that in `stuff.rs` it is not needed anywhere else. What you want to do instead of using an absolute path is `use super::a::StructA` where super takes you up one level from the module it is used in.